# webpack with serverless isn't working with folder structure

Tags: webpack, serverless-framework

I have few serverless project created without using ES6/ES7 support. In our new project, i wanted to integrate this with serverless but not able to get it going.

Here is my serverless.yml file

```js
#sls offline start --skipCacheInvalidation
service: test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10 # set node.js runtime
  memorySize: 1024 # set the maximum memory of the Lambdas in Megabytes
  timeout: 300 # the timeout is 10 seconds (default is 6 seconds)
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'} #${self:provider.stage} # setting the env stage to dev, this will be visible in the routes
  region: us-east-1
  logRetentionInDays: 14 # Set the default RetentionInDays for a CloudWatch LogGroup
  deploymentBucket: 
    name: api-test
  # custom:
  #   stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  environment: ${file(env.yml):${self:provider.stage}}


plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

# serverless optimization
package:
  individually: true

# serverless-webpack configuration
# Enable auto-packing of external modules
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js 
    includeModules: true

functions: 
  createCampaign:
    handler: src/Campaign.CreateCampaign
    name : campaign-createcampaign-${self:provider.stage} #custom lambda name instead of auto generated
    description: To create campaign
    events:
      - http:
        path: campaign
        method: post
        cors: true

  getAllCampaign:
    handler: src/Campaign.GetCampaign
    name : campaign-getall-${self:provider.stage} #custom lambda name instead of auto generated
    description: To retrieve all campaign
    events:
      - http:
        path: campaign
        method: get
        cors: true
```

My campaign.js is under /src folder in my code. I tried this using https://medium.com/@kilgarenone/write-es6-es7-in-serverless-framework-using-babel-7-and-webpack-4-5bd742168e1a
My webpack config is following.

```js
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  //entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  entry: {handler : './src/Campaign.js'},
  target: 'node',
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false,
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false,
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My package.json is

```js
{
  "name": "orim-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.0.1",
    "serverless-offline": "^4.9.4",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.5",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.12"
  }
}
```

My .babelrc file is

```js
{
  "plugins": ["source-map-support"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "8.10"
        }
      }
    ],
    
  ]
}
```

When i execute sls offline start --SkipCacheInvalidateion, i get following warning

WARNING in ./src/Campaign.js 5:12-29
"export 'connectToDatabase' was not found in '../db'

And it seems like webpack and babel-loader isn't transpile my entire code

Comment: Nobody to help yet ?

Comment: It would help if you posted the `src/Campign.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me and I got solutions and finally the examplebel-webpack-4 was used in serverless-webpack
I don't know why the error happens with settings for you. But for me using the example I send here below solved my problem. And maybe it will help yours or other colleagues who face this.

https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/blob/master/examples/babel-webpack-4/webpack.config.js

Alright, I needed to install some packages after cloning the webpack.config but this is simple. Good luck to you and everyone.